# Proving if two samples hides a value?

Tags: one-time-pad, perfect-secrecy

Given two values

- $r'-r \mod q$
- $i - r \mod q$

Where

- $r',r$ sampled randomly from $Z_q$
- while i is pick arbitrarily from $Z_q$ and a secret

Can we claim that this hides $i$?

Here is my sketch:
Distribution of above samples is indistinguishable to

- $r'' \mod q$
- $i - r \mod q$

Where $r''$ is randomly picked from $Z_q$
If that is true then clearly it is indistinguishable from following as r is randomly picked

- $r'' \mod q$
- $r''' \mod q$

$r'''$ is randomly picked from $Z_q$

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE Why there are two values? The second is enough. What is the probability of an adversary guessing $i$ from $i - r \bmod q$ ($Q$ is really bad there)?

Comment: @kelalaka problem definition require sending two samples structured the way I mentioned above, $Q$ is quite bit lets say 128 bits long

Comment: I think the question ask to use contrapositive, assume it doesn't hide, then you can get $r$ there you can conclude that the adversary can find the random coins.

Comment: Note that this is considered homework and hints should and have been given in the comments...

Comment: it is not an homework though this is part of larger problem that I am proving

Comment: Well, if you perform a list of modular additions or subtractions of a key stream on an alphabet modulo the size of the alphabet then you have an OTP. If you use $Z_q$ as the alphabet then $i$ can be your one "character" message.